# Could not optimize methods

Tags: scala, inline, tail-recursion

Here is a minimal code that raise the compilation error 'Recursive call not in tail position'. However, I'm using an `@inline` and the recursive call *is* in tail position. The reason why I'm using this `@inline` is that I have the code pf the original `reccall` duplicated twice.

```
import scala.annotation._
object Test {
  @tailrec private def test(i: Int): Int = {
    @inline def reccall(i: Int): Int = test(i-1)
    i match {
      case 0 => 0
      case i => reccall(i)
    }
  }
}
```

I've looked at the answers [Recursive call not in tail position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508800/recursive-call-not-in-tail-position) [@tailrec why does this method not compile with 'contains a recursive call not in tail position'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358283/tailrec-why-does-this-method-not-compile-with-contains-a-recursive-call-not-in) but they do not apply to my case. Using Scala 2.12

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582515/make-method-actually-inline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears, the way `@inline` is implemented is that it still passes the parameter via stack. The jump is eliminated, by inserting the code inline, but the stack is still used for the arguments. This makes it impossible to be in a tail position, because the stack needs to be cleaned up after the call is completed.

Besides, annotating a function with `@inline` does not *guarantee* that the optimizer will inline it, just that it will "try especially hard".

Comment: I like your answer very much. It emphasizes that the questioner hoped that `@inline` would eliminate the extra stack frame.

Comment: Do you have any reference proving that @inline is actually still pushing the arguments into the stack, and not to local variables as I would expect ?

Comment: Do, I don't :) I was just guessing, that it _might_ be doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the mechanism of how tail recursion is actualized in JVM is explained in following way:

> Scala, in the case of tail recursion, can eliminate the creation of a
>   new stack frame and just re-use the current stack frame.  The stack
>   never gets any deeper, no matter how many times the recursive call is
>   made.

So in your case it cannot reuse the current stack frame belonging to the `test` method since it MUST create a new stack frame for the `reccall` method anyway.

Recursive call is implicit in this case, made from another method. So I believe you cannot really have tail recursion implemented for such case.

You may just remove the `reccall` method altogether and write `case i => test(i-1)` and then compiler will not complain.

NOTE: also I believe `@inline` has nothing to do here and is not essential in this example, since if I remove it - compiler still complains the same reason.

Comment: The call to `reccall` should not be inlined manually it as it factors a lot of code in my real example. Please, understand that this is a simplified code, not my full code.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer, I understand now. I did not initially get the idea that you supposed that `@inline` will eliminate that stack frame and will push args via local variables. Now I see.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `@inline` is strictly advisory: it doesn't guarantee that the compiler will inline the function.  Since `@tailrec` only works if it's absolutely guaranteed that the tail-calls can be eliminated, this means that using `@tailrec` has to assume no inlining.